# Spaces are not being inserted into database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a form field that accepts large text from users. It is basically a description field. After accepting the text, it enters it into the database. Now the text is being entered, but the spaces are not being recognized.

Can you help?

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_post['text']);
```

Thanks.

Comment: spaces means? between the words or right and left space??

Comment: Could you post some context, i.e. more code?

Comment: Oh no. Space means the space between paragraphs.

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the escaping part.

Comment: You mean line breaks, correct?

Comment: show us the query for a better response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean line breaks.

Those are most likely not lost, but get swallowed when you output the text - HTML doesn't honour normal line breaks, it needs the `<br>`  tag to do that.

Use `nl2br()` when outputting the text to get line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your escape part

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['text']);
```

Comment: Nope, this is the mysqli variant: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @pekka you are right, the is still an issue with the post variable